# Analogon zu "hospitalisieren"

Tags: single-word-request

Der Begriff "Hospitalisieren" meint, so wie ich es verstehe, einen – kritisch gesehenen – Vorgang, bei dem eine als krank definierte Person in eine Klinik eingewiesen wird. *(Manchmal wird auch die Passivform verwendet, wenn man ausdrücken möchte, dass jemand in einer Klinik krankenhausspezifische Symptome entwickelt hat.)*

In Gesprächen über einen alten, dement werdenden Menschen hatte ich das Gefühl, dass einige Gesprächsteilnehmer dazu neigten, Prozessen, die ich für "nicht-krank", sondern für altersbedingte und natürliche Verfallserscheinungen halte, eine Charakterisierung zu geben, die zum Gebiet der manifesten Krankheiten gehören (Das bedeutet, sie denken/argumentieren in der Kategorie "Diagnose", z. B. mit den Begrifflichkeiten des ICD).

In den Gesprächen bewertete ich diese Denkrichtung, ähnlich wie bei dem Begriff "Hospitalisieren", gefühlsmäßig mit einer negativen Färbung. *(Eine ähnliche Ebene der Kritik an einem Denken/Handeln, wie "Hospitalisieren", wäre vielleicht auch der Begriff "Kriminalisierung": Dieser Begriff wurde meines Wissens eingeführt, um auszudrücken, dass ein eigentlich im Rahmen des Alltags liegendes Handeln unangemessenerweise auf die Ebene eines strafbewehrten, offiziösen Deliktes gehoben wird.)* Als Bezeichnung für dieses Denken in Diagnosen und im Zuschreiben von Krankheitskategorien schlug jemand "stigmatisieren" vor. Das legt den Fokus aber auf einen anderen Aspekt.

Ein naiver Vorschlag, der aber von der Wortkonstruktion am ehesten zuträfe, wäre sowas wie "Krankifizieren" – aber ich denke, es gibt sicherlich ein geeignetes Wort.

[update] Fast meine ich, "pathologisieren" wäre geeignet, aber das ist es wohl auch nicht. Die Endung "…fizieren" scheint mir hingegen in die richtige Richtung zu gehen, sie lässt eine Künstlichkeit bei den gemachten Zuschreibung anklingen. Womöglich suche ich also ein Wort, das solch eine Endung hat.

[update 2]: im Nachklang an Em1' "Schubladendenken", das ein wenig mehr die grundsätzliche Richtung meines Kritikpunktes angibt. Diesen Aspekt beibehalten und dann sowas wie "Iatroisieren" oder wie in einem Tipp in einem anderen Posting "Medikalisieren" (dort als soziologischer Fachbegriff beigebracht) hinzufügen – das kommt der Sache schon näher, aber verringert wieder den Aspekt der Allgemeinheit in Em1' Vorschlag. "Morbifizieren" hätte noch den künstlichen, aktiven, gestalterischen Aspekt (den solches Denken, das daraus entstehende Interagieren mit dem alten Menschen und schließlich das sich daraus ableitende Handeln haben mag) durch diese Wort-Endung "…fizieren".

Mal sehen, ob noch eine überzeugendere Lösung kommt. Vielleicht sollte man sogar nach den Latinismen und Graecismen zurückkommen zur eigenen Sprache: jemanden "krank reden" – wenn man das im konkreten Gespräch ganz genau ausdrücken und 'rüberbringen könnte im Sinne von Kritik an einer effektiven – wenn auch vielleicht ungewollten – Zuschreibung; jemanden "krank schreiben" … na ja, das hätte dann bereits eine ulkige Doppelbedeutung, die dann irreführend würde.

Comment: Sorry, ich hab zwar im Groben ne Ahnung, worauf du hinaus willst, aber der Text ist absolut unverständlich. Du beginnst Sätze, fügst Nebensätze ein, aber beendest nicht deinen Hauptsatz. Mir ist nicht wirklich klar, für was du ein *geeignetes Wort* suchst? Für den Prozess, welchen Menschen im Alter erleiden, wenn sie z.b. an Demenz erkranken? Oder suchst du ein Wort für das *Diagnostizieren* einer altersbedingten Erkrankung? Und wozu neigten eigentlich die Gesprächsteilnehmer, das stellst du nirgends klar. (Zumindest kapiere ich es nicht. Was ist "Prozesse anheften"?)

Comment: @Em1: Sorry, aber ich finde Deine Kritik etwas harsch. Ich hatte keine besonderen Probleme, die Frage zu verstehen, und ich sehe auch keine nicht-beendeten Hauptsätze: 'Der Begriff "Hospitalisieren" meint den Vorgang, einen als krank Definierten in eine Klinik zu bringen.' Ich habe bloß 'einen' durch 'den' ersetzt und 'Definierten' groß geschrieben.

Comment: au wei :). Ok, ich sehe zu, den Text leserlicher zu machen. Je weniger bei einer Frage mein Gedanke bereits sortiert ist, desto schlechter/verworrener auch mein schriftlicher Ausdruck...- sorry....

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Ich habe versucht, deinen Text nach besten Gewissen zu verbessern. Ich hoffe, dass ich alles richtig verstanden habe. Andernfalls führe entw. einen Rollback durch, oder passe die entsprechenden Fehlinterpretationen an. Der Text ist immer noch etwas holprig, aber ich habe zumindest versucht, den komplizierten Satz in der Mitte etwas zu optimieren.

Comment: Hi @Em1, alles im grünen Bereich, danke für die Mühe. Ich hab auch noch ein bißchen gebürstet. Immerhin scheine ich durch diese Nacharbeiten der Sache sprachlich ein bißchen näher zu kommen...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Was hälst du von "*Schubladendenken*": Angewohnheit, eine Sache einer exklusiven/vorgefassten Kategorie zuzuweisen. (siehe [WIKTIONARY](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Schubladendenken)) (Achja, PS: Ich hab mein Downvote zurückgezogen)

Comment: @Em1 : nicht schlecht, habe ich mittlerweile auch schon erwogen. Was mir daran gefällt ist, daß es den geistigen Habitus, der als Grundlage des kritisierten Denkens/Redens/Handelns angenommen werden kann, in den Blick nimmt, was mir selbst und meinen Intentionen auch eher entspricht. Aber hier geht es noch ein bißchen weiter - für mich schwingt da noch so etwas wie ein "sich-ausliefern an Über-ich-mäßige Autoritäten" (also den allgegenwärtigen $Arzt/Iatros oder überhaupt den medizinisch-technischen Diskurs) - aber diese Diskussion führte jetzt wohl zu weit weg...

Comment: `Jmd. als krank abstempeln` würde ich noch vorschlagen, aber habe das Gefühl, Du suchst ein einzelnes Wort. Manchmal gibt es einfach keins. :) Das ist allerdings m.E. kein Analogon zu 'hospitalisieren', aber evtl. für das, was den Alten in Deinem Beispiel widerfährt, eine passende Bezeichnung.

Comment: @user: Der Vorschlag gefällt mir gut! Und für das englische _succeed_ gibt es ja auch kein einzelnes Wort im Deutschen. (Deine Verwirrung oben verstehe ich übrigens nicht recht - war das nicht schon mit meiner Bemerkung darüber hinreichend klar? Statt _einen Vorgang_ musste es einfach _den Vorgang_ heißen.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt: (Etwas späte Antwort) Mit großgeschriebenem "Definierten" oder so wie jetzt, mit Person, geht es. Ob Dein Kommentar für mich schon sichtbar war, oder ob ich aus irgendwelchen Gründen mehr als 11 Minuten für meinen gebraucht habe weiß ich jetzt nicht mehr.

Comment: Die Betrachtung leidet m.E. an der allerdings verbreiteten Gewohnheit einen allgemeinen Vorgang (kriminalisieren, hospitalisieren) zu bewerten, oder zu meinen, dass eine solche Charakterisierung notwendig mit einer Wertung verbunden ist. Wenn der Gesetzgeber ein Verhalten abstellen will, dann verbietet er es, er kriminalisiert es. Ob ich dafür oder dagegen bin - ich kann es doch beide Male `kriminalisieren` nennen. Das Wort überdramatisiert nicht, noch ist es ein Euphemismus. Wieso soll damit gleich eine Wertung verbunden sein?

Comment: "...fizieren" muss keine Künstlichkeit bezeichnen. In der Natur kommen etwa natürliche Mumifizierungsprozesse vor. Siehe auch "modifizieren", "infizieren", "identifizieren" ...

Comment: Diese Frage ist sehr umstaändlich und zum Teil unklar. Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: Du scheinst *hospitalisieren* grundsätzlich als "zwangsweise ins Hospital einweisen" zu verstehen  - Das heißt es aber gar nicht. Man kann sich aber durchaus auch selbst und freiwillig *hospitalisieren* lassen. Von daher scheint mir schon diese Grundannahme, auf der der Rest der Frage fußt, nicht richtig zu sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gesucht ist also eine "*Bezeichnung für dieses Denken in Diagnosen und im Zuschreiben von Krankheitskategorien*", das nicht angebracht und überzogen erscheint, da das der Diagnose zugrundeliegende Gesehene dem die Bezeichnung Verwendende eigentlich als "normal" bzw. als bereits anders erklärbar erscheint? Ich werfe mal drei Varianten in den Ring:

- **medizinischer Paralogismus** (wenn die Fehlerhaftigkeit betont werden soll)
- **rabulistische Diagnostik** (wenn eine Absicht hinter dem Diagnosefehler betont werden soll)
- **syllogistische (diagnostische) Koinzidenzignoranz** (wenn der Hang zur Überbewertung betont werden soll)

Aber das sind auch nur mehr (oder weniger!) gelungene Verklausulierungen, um Kritik an einer Diagnose selber zu formulieren. Das trifft vielleicht nicht unbedingt die gewünschte Betonung der Denkweise selber. Meiner Meinung nach umschreiben die bereits genannten Bezeichnungen "*pathologisieren*" und "*überdiagnostizieren*" oder die schlichten Verben "*überinterpretieren*" bzw. "*fehldeuten*" das Verhalten recht deutlich. Wenn der Hang zu diesem Verhalten betont werden soll, kann man all die oben stehenden Begriffe oder natürlich auch die genannen Verben mit dem Zusatz "Affinität" kombinieren. Daher mein Vorschlag Nummer 4:

- "**Pathologisierungsaffinität**"

Answer (score 9):

Wenn ich diese sehr umständlich formulierte Frage richtig verstehe, läuft sie darauf hinaus, jemanden fälschlicherweise als krank zu klassifizieren. "Pathologisieren" trifft das wohl am besten.

Comment: Schade, dass diese nicht mehr Upvotes erhält. *Pathologisieren* bezeichnet das als unangemessen empfundene Darstellen/Wahrnehmen/Konzeptualisieren eines Phänomens als krankhaft. Der Begriff passt also hier genau.

Answer (score 2):

So wie man eine Erkrankung [*diagnostizieren*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/diagnostizieren) kann, kann man es dabei auch übertreiben. Ich kenne in diesem Zusammenhang den Begriff:

> überdiagnostizieren

Dies entspricht genau dem Gegenteil dessen, was man als *"unterdiagnostizieren"* (eine schwere Erkankung nicht ernst genug nehmen) bezeichnet.

Comment: Nein, das wäre nicht das worauf ich hinaus will. Ich möchte einen Ausdruck, um die Geneigtheit dazu zu bezeichnen, jemanden eine (offizielle) Krankheitsdiagnose anzuheften wogegen man mit Alltagsbegriffen/Alltagsvorstellungen noch auskommen könnte/sollte. Nicht eine *Über*diagnostizierung meine ich, sondern *die Bereitschaft*, sich überhaupt schon in das Gebiet der Krankheitenklassifizierung ("Diagnosen stellen") zu begeben während ein Opponent (hier also ich) der Meinung ist, daß das als solches noch gar nicht angemessen ist.

Comment: Schon klar, genau das versteht man unter *überdiagnostizieren*, nämlich eine Diagnose zu stellen, wo noch gar keine Krankheit vorliegt. Tipp: Google nach `"überdiagnostizieren"` befragen.

Answer (score 2):

Zunächst bitte VORSICHT:

[Hospitalisieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hospitalisieren):

> 1. (schweizerisch) [unter bestimmten Umständen zwangsweise] in ein
>      Krankenhaus oder Pflegeheim einweisen
> 2. (Medizin, Psychologie, Pädagogik) an Hospitalismus (1) leiden

Wenn Du also in Deutschland publizierst - auf keinen Fall "hospitalisieren"!

---

Ich finde Takkats Vorschlag ziemlich gut: Wenn  man "überdiagnostizieren" nicht auf einen bestimmten Zustand bezieht (wie es OP wohl verstanden hat), sondern auf den Akt des Diagnostizierens selbst, passt es m.E. ziemlich gut.

Auf der Hand liegt "pathologisieren" - was spricht dagegen? [edited]

Ansonsten bleiben wohl nur (mehr oder weniger geschraubte) Umschreibungen:

- "übertriebene Diagnosebereitschaft"
- "Schnellschussdiagnostik"

Wenn man's unbedingt pseudowissenschaftlich/lateinisch will:

- "Präcox-Diagnostik"?

---

Oh, und "meinen" ist im Deutschen nicht analog zum Englischen "to mean" verwendbar... :)

Comment: Hmm, "pathologisieren" hatte ich ja schon angesprochen. Nochmal kurz zur "Über-diagnostik". Vielleicht wird mein Einwand hierzu klarer wenn man sich die gelegentliche Situation ausmalt, wie die junge Mama/der junge Papa das Baby im Arm hat und bei einem ihnen neuen Ereignis nach dem Arzt/nach der Schwester suchen - und die Oma ihnen erklärt, daß es ganz normal für Babies ist, nach dem Essen ein Bäuerchen herauszulassen. Hier -so meine ich- ist nicht mehr oder weniger medizinische Diagnostik angebracht, sondern ich finde "Diagnose"-Denken hier als unangebracht: "als solches". (...cont...)

Comment: (...cont...) Aber mir scheint, das geht wohl etwas zu weit für german.stackexchange. Vielleicht kommt noch etwas überzeugendes, was ich bisher simpel übersehen habe, ansonsten müßte ich wohl eine von den vorhandenen Antworten auf "akzeptiert" setzen...

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Das Beispiel mit dem Baby klingt eher nach *Überreaktion* ;p

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Sorry - pathologisieren hatte ich übersehen... warum ist es das "wohl auch nicht"? Das ist doch genau was Du meinst? (Jedenfalls zum "überdiagnostizieren": Wir reden aneinander vorbei. Versuch es mal als Analogbildung zu "übertreiben" zu sehen, wo auch keine unmittelbare Beziehung zu "treiben" besteht.)

Answer (score 1):

In einem Interview mit einem Psychiater kommt das Wort "***medizinalisieren***" vor. Kompliziert, aber die Intention des Sprechers trifft genau meine Frage:
([link](https://www.heise.de/tp/features/In-der-Psychiatrie-wird-es-wohl-immer-einen-unerklaerbaren-Rest-geben-4668474.html))

> Ludger Tebartz van Elst: Positiv ist, dass die Toleranz dann wächst. Ich glaube schon, dass die Menschen weniger Angst vor einem Nachbarn mit einer Psychose haben, wenn sie darüber nicht nur Halbwissen haben und das im Sinne des genetischen Denkens von vor hundert Jahren missverstehen.
>
> Negativ ist wohl, dass mit der Psychiatrisierung auch die Robustheit der Menschen abzunehmen scheint. Nehmen wir an, ich habe nach dem Verlust eines geliebten Menschen einen Durchhänger. In meiner Kindheit auf dem Dorf dachte man: *"Der hat jetzt eine schwere Zeit, das geht auch wieder vorbei."*
>
> Heute bekommt das schnell das Etikett "Depression", es wird dadurch ***medizinalisiert*** und man gibt bei einem, der einfach nur drei Schicksalsschläge gleichzeitig wegstecken muss, Antidepressiva. Dadurch kann auch eine subjektive oder existentielle Komponente verloren gehen, die für manche Menschen von großer Bedeutung ist.
>
> Die eigene Verzweiflung wird dann nicht mehr als Herausforderung durch das Schicksal, sondern als Krankheit gedeutet. Das Selbstbild und auch das Fremdbild kann sich negativ verändern, wenn man solche Probleme als Krankheit versteht.

Answer (score 1):

Es geht anscheinend darum, ein Wort zu (er)finden mit der ungefähren Bedeutung ‚*einem altersbedingten Verhaltensmerkmal oder einer eingeschränkten Leistungsausprägung einen Krankheitswert zuschreiben*‘. Meine  Anmerkungen:

Wenn es um Bedeutung und Verwendungsmöglichkeiten von Wörtern geht, ist es immer gut, von Beispielen, d.h. von Sätzen oder einer Satzfolge auszugehen. Ich kann mir z.B. keinen Kontext vorstellen, in dem *hospitalisieren* die angestrebte Bedeutung auch nur im Entferntesten träfe. Falls ich damit richtig liege, führt der hier gewählte Titel „Analogon zu *hospitalisieren*“ in die Irre.

Beim Übersetzen stellt sich häufig das Problem, dass es für ein Wort der Ausgangssprache kein Pendant in der Zielsprache gibt. Dann muss man die gewünschte Bedeutung entweder umschreiben, sie durch einen mehrwortigen Ausdruck ersetzen oder das Wort so übernehmen, wie es dasteht, ggf. mit einer Fußnote versehen. Ich frage mich, was der Grund dafür ist, dass es ein einziges Wort sein muss, das die Ziel-Bedeutung tragen soll.

Beim Erfinden von Wörtern bedient man sich oft bereits vorhandener reihenbildender Muster, hier kämen *-isieren* oder *-ifizieren* in Frage. Derartige Reihungen sind mit Assoziationen verbunden, die bei den einzelnen Rezipienten sehr verschieden bis hin zu sich gegenseitig ausschließend ausfallen können. Darüber wird oft ausgiebig diskutiert, ohne dass man zu einer eindeutigen Lösung käme, z.B. hinsichtlich der *-er*-Endung bei von Verben abgeleiteten Personenbezeichungen in der Genderdiskussion (die so lustige Vermeidungsgebilde wie *Arbeitnehmende* hervorbringt). Ich traue mir da kein Urteil zu. *Medizinalisierung* bzw. sein Ausgangswort *medizinalisieren* halte ich persönlich für nicht gut geglückt, es ist im Kontext als *mit medizinischen Kategorien erfassen* verständlich, bleibt aber wohl ein Okkasionalismus. Als gut geglückt empfinde ich Wortbildungen, die sofort einen Aha-Effekt auslösen, bei denen ein oder mehrere Erkenntnisfunken überspringen, die sich idealerweise ob man will oder nicht sofort im Gedächtnis einnisten.

Damit ist man in mehrfacher Hinsicht bei Bewertungsfragen. Hinsichtlich der Normalität von altersbedingten Ausprägungen wie *nachlassende Gedächtnisleistung*, *Unorganisiertheit*, *Überforderungsgefühle*, *Konzentrationsmängel*, *eingeschränkte Mobilität*, *sozialer Rückzug* usw. wird es statistische Aussagen geben, wobei die jeweiligen Etikettierungen bereits deutliche Wertungen enthalten. Inwieweit große Abweichungen von den Normalitätswerten als *krank* bewertet werden können, scheint eine ewige Frage der Psychologie und der darauf bezogenen medizinischen Fachrichtungen (Psychiatrie, Psychotherapie, …) zu sein.

In der deutschen Wikipedia findet man übrigens unter Pathologisierung folgende Erklärung:

> „In einem umfassenderen Sinn bezieht sich Pathologisierung nicht nur
> auf die Bewertung von psychischen und sozialen Phänomenen als
> krankhaft. Vielmehr geht es auch um Abweichungen vom medizinisch
> definierten Normalzustand, die keine nennenswerte
> Funktionsbeeinträchtigung mit sich bringen, von den meisten
> Betroffenen als nicht nachteilig empfunden werden oder – wie Symptome
> des Alterns – als normale körperliche Vorgänge verstanden werden.“

Doch eigentlich genau das Gesuchte, oder nicht?

Comment: Mmmh, vielen Dank! Aus dem Abstand einiger Monate heraus klingt "pathologisieren" sehr passend; ich habe im Moment nicht genau präsent, warum ich damals diesem Begriff ausgewichen bin. Möglicherweise, weil "pathologisieren" im Vergleich zu dem, was ich suchte, zu allgemein verwendbar erschien. Mir ging es darum, diese Tendenz zu benennen, daß man einer Erscheinung im natürlichen Alterungsprozeß ein medizinisches Label anheftet - sozusagen um ihr für den institutionalisierten medizinischen Betrieb "Respektabilität" zu verschaffen. (...)

Comment: (...) Möglicherweise deshalb meine damalige Hinwendung zu "medizinalisieren" (was nach meinem Sprachgefühl sicher ein ungewöhnlicher, umständlicher und un-schöner Begriff ist)

Comment: @Gottfried Helms: Danke für die Antwort.