# In der Diagnose links, rechts: Aus wessen Sicht?

Tags: word-usage

Vielleicht kann mir jemand auf eine Frage zur deutschen Fachsprache helfen.

Wenn ich eine Diagnose von einem Arzt in der Hand halte, ist dann *links,
rechts* aus der Sicht des Patienten formuliert, oder aus der Sicht des Arztes?

Also: *Bein links* bedeutet das *mein linkes Bein* oder 
*mein rechtes Bein*?

Comment: hab ich mich zwar selber bisher nie gefragt aber es ist wirklich eine echt richtig gute Frage :)

Comment: Mir wäre ein Medizin Stackexchange lieber, wenn es so etwas geben würde. Aber dieses hier scheint ab und zu für solche Fragen verwendet zu werden: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/analogon-zu-hospitalisieren

Comment: @CookieMonster Das mit dem Analogon zu hospitalisieren ist aber eine ganz andere Geschichte, und hat gar nicht so viel mit der Medizin ansich oder sonst was zu tuen, sondern es geht wirklich direkt um einen Begriff der deutschen Sprache. Das Analogon zu hospitalisieren kann man nur hier stellen; deine Frage hättest du auch auf ELU, FLU, RLU, ... stellen können. Das ist der Unterschied ;)

Comment: Vorrausgesetzt diese Sprachregionen halten sich auch an the anatomische Nomenklatur, was man aber nicht voraussetzen kann. Es fängt schon damit an, dass man sich fragen muss ob es "Links" und "Rechts" wie wir es kennen in der jeweiligen Sprachregion gibt: http://uppsala.academia.edu/IngridMaier/Papers/1351781/Die_Semantik_vonrechts_undlinks_auf_Russisch_und_die_Dimension_des_Personenbezugs

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die Seitenbezeichnungen sind **exakt** so, wie Du es bei Dir selbst sagen würdest:

> Meine rechte Hand schmerzt = Der Patient hat Schmerzen in der rechten Hand.

Grundlage ist die [anatomische Nomenklatur](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomenklatur_%28Anatomie%29), in der Seitenangaben aus der Sicht des Körpers definiert sind.

Comment: Ja, das macht Sinn. Hast Du zufällig eine Quelle, verschieden von http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_und_rechts#Personen ?

Comment: "anatomische Nomenklatur" Oki Doki. Informell wird es auch hier nochmal bestätigt: http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme49/article5708754.html